# how to relate two fields with same date but different time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get the Transaction data with date difference for "DATE" (Transaction Date) versus ENCODED Date (Actual Date),

I tried relating the two fields with transaction dates, but the problem is the other field have a timestamp which mean i cant relate to the other fields with no timestamp

```
select
    cast( cdvdate AS varchar(12) ) as Transaction_Date,
    cast( UpdateDate AS varchar(20) ) as Encoded_Date,
    ApprovedDate
from
    cdvhdr
where
    cdvdate != updatedate
```

I expect the result with no same transaction date  and encoded date like this

```
Transaction_Date    Encoded_Date            ApprovedDate
Jan  4 2016         Jan 23 2016 10:54AM     2016-01-24 16:16:37.000
```

but it is showing result with same day because of the timestamp

```
Transaction_Date    Encoded_Date            ApprovedDate
Jan 26 2016         Jan 26 2016 10:58AM     2016-01-26 13:42:32.000
Jan 26 2016         Jan 26 2016 11:07AM     2016-01-26 13:42:55.000
Jan 26 2016         Jan 26 2016 11:09AM     2016-01-26 13:41:49.000
Jan 26 2016         Jan 26 2016 11:11AM     2016-01-26 13:42:09.000
```

Comment: Tip: Never process date/time information as strings/varchar in SQL. Use the built-in date functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply convert the values to dates for comparisons:

```
where convert(date, cdvdate) <> convert(date, updatedate)
```

If one of these is already a `date`, there is obviously no need for the conversion.

SQL Server is good about using indexes with conversion to a `date`.  Although an index cannot be used in this case (because two columns are being compared), it is a good habit to avoid `datediff()` in the `where` clause, unless you really need it.  In this case, you don't really need it.

Comment: Thank you i will try this one also

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATEDIFF(DAY,cdvdate,updatedate)<>0` in where condition. It will compare only dates.

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted.  The answer is correct and pretty much the same as Metal's upvoted answer.

Comment: Late to the party, but I upvoted also. This is the better of the answers here. No casting, no converting. You want something on the same day as something else. Brilliantly simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast your `datetime` to `date`.

```
SELECT Cast(cdvdate AS VARCHAR(12))    AS Transaction_Date, 
       Cast(updatedate AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Encoded_Date, 
       approveddate 
FROM   cdvhdr 
WHERE  Datediff(dd, Cast(cdvdate AS DATE), Cast(updatedate AS DATE)) != 0
```

Comment: Wow thank ,you solve my problem but can you explain what happen. I mean how do you relate the two fields ?

Comment: based on datediff() function if its equal to 0 it means the same

Comment: As far as I can see, you could also (at least in SQL Server) use `WHERE CAST(cdvdate AS DATE) = CAST(updatedate AS DATE)`. I do not see the need for using the DATEDIFF function here.